# K8S PODS from workers can not access to private repository deployed on Master

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, docker-registry

I have created a K8S Cluster with 3 nodes ( 1 Master + 2 Workers / CNI flannel).

I have deployed a private repository localhost:31320 on Master using docker registry ( secret has been correctly defined in deployment registry file).

My issue is that I can not pull image from private registry ( it works correctly on Master)
I get error:

"Warning  Failed     4m15s (x6 over 22m)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "localhost:31320/automation-platform/base:11.0.15.1.centos.7.9.2009.2": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error while pulling image: Get http://localhost:31320/v1/repositories/automation-platform/base/images: dial tcp [::1]:31320: connect: connection refused
"

I do not know how to investigate it and why my workers does not acces to private repo ( connection refused ?)
I don't see any error under kubelet logs of worker node.

Note that my deployment files have been already used on a previous network and all worked correctly. The difference I saw is that I used K8S 1.20.
Now, I use K8S 1.23

Does someone could tell how I can investigate to see the reason of my problem ?

Regards,

Comment: Isn't localhost the worker node's localhost here and you rather want to access the repository on the master node?

Comment: yes I would like to access to registry on master node. How I can specify to my wortkers that localhost:31320 corresponds ro my master ? On my previous cluster, I do not remenber to have configure something special. .. workers accessed to it ..

Comment: I would assume the master node has an IP, a DNS record or something that you can use to identify it instead of using localhost. `kubectl get nodes -o wide` might help here. Other options are port-forwarding or deploying the registry on all nodes, other people might have better ideas on this though :)

Comment: yes really network pb... manually, for instance if i pull my image from terminal with "docker pull <master_ip>:31320/... it works . But under the pod , even if I change for this same config , I've got the same error. I really do not know how it can work before but i am sure that docker command on worker -> pull localhost:31320/ command is able to pull image from repository on master ! .. I do not know what configuration is different but it worked ...

Answer (score 0):

try to edit /etc/containerd/config.toml and add your registry ip:port like this
{
"insecure-registries":
["172.16.4.93:5000"]
}

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried without success ! I try to investigate how it could run before ( without additional configuration !). How my workers could consider localhost:31320 has a private repo on Master. I really did not understand how it was possible =